# Remove any text inside square brackets in r

Tags: r, regex, text-mining, square-bracket

I would like to remove all the words inside square brackets as well as the brackets themselves. For example,

```
text = c('[Verse 1]', '[Verse 1: Dua Lipa]', '[Corus]', '[Corus: Ann Marie & Ed Sheeran]')
```

Like above, the length of words inside the bracket are not constant. So I need a function that can identify the position of `[` and `]` in order to erase all the words, numbers and symbols in between. Is there any function able to do that?

Comment: What tool are you using and what have you tried already?

Comment: Hey Corion, I'm using R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may remove all substrings within square brackets using

```
gsub("\\[[^][]*]", "", text)
```

The pattern matches an open square bracket, then any zero or more chars other than square brackets, and then a close square bracket.

Comment: OMG, Thanks a lot Wiktor!! It's so simple and clean. Great :D

Comment: Then How could I apply this to the case of `<, >` instead of `[, ]`?  I'm really bad at regular expressions.

Comment: @Jean `gsub("<[^<>]*>", "", text)`. What were you trying?

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I got the intuition. I'm doing text mining with song lyrics. There are some parts unnecessary so that's the reason.

Comment: Yeah I did. Thanks again!