# R: replace interior square brackets in presence of multiple brackets

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am trying to convert an expression such as `[[a], [b]]` into `list(c(a), c(b))` (basically a java dictionary into R list). As a first step, I would like to convert each inner expression `[a]` into an equivalent `c(a)`. According to [How to replace square brackets with curly brackets using R's regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608060/how-to-replace-square-brackets-with-curly-brackets-using-rs-regex), I can use a nice regular expression `"\\[(.*?)\\]"` or also `\\[([^]]*)\\]`.

This will work when there is only one `[]` parenthesis, but not multiple ones like `[[` as it will capture the first, resulting in `"c([a), c(b])"` instead of `"[c(a), c(b)]"`. How can I make sure I am only matching the inner parenthesis in a call that contains multiple `[[], []]`?

```r
vec <- c("[a]", "[[a], [b]]")
gsub("\\[(.*?)\\]", "c(\\1)", vec)
#> [1] "c(a)"         "c([a), c(b])"
gsub("\\[([^]]*)\\]", "c(\\1)", vec)
#> [1] "c(a)"         "c([a), c(b)]"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: (Oops, I thought I only had a "vote" to reopen. @WiktorStribiżew, I was hoping for a more democratic solution than just over-riding your closure, though I still think it's the right move. Thoughts?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Remove any text inside square brackets in r](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52677243/3358272) suggests how to deal with the regex itself, it doesn't address the "nested" component of the problem.

You can run it multiple times until there are no more changes.

```r
vec <- c("[a]", "[[a], [b]]")
(vec2 <- gsub("\\[([^][]*)\\]", "c(\\1)", vec))
# [1] "c(a)"         "[c(a), c(b)]"
(vec3 <- gsub("\\[([^][]*)\\]", "c(\\1)", vec2))
# [1] "c(a)"          "c(c(a), c(b))"
```

The change is to disallow both opening `[` and closing `]` brackets in the regex, which should only match the inner-most (no brackets).

It should be feasible to nest this in a `while` loop that exits as soon as no change is detected.