# Remove string with brackets

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I've got a dataframe which looks like this:

|  | X1 |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | [0005] |
| 8 |  |
| 9 | [I/0006] |
| 10 | Athenaeum. |
| 11 | Eine Zeitschrift |

I've got these numbers in brackets throughout the entire dataframe and want to delete all of the brackets as well as their content.

I've tried two approaches so far, both of them haven't worked. With `filter` I've tried this:

```
A1_msw<- A1798 %>%
  filter(str_detect(A1_msw, "[:digit:]")) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = bigram, input = X1, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>% 
  na.omit(A1_msw)
```

The problem here is that since there are sometimes characters in the brackets, it only deletes the rows with *only* digits in it. It also removes everything with punctuation, which is a problem since there are now words missing. The result looks like this:

|  | bigram |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | i 0006 |
| 13 | eine zeitschrift |

I've also tried it with `gsub` but I think I've got the syntax wrong (but also don't know how it's supposed to look):

```
A1_msw<- A1798 %>%
  gsub(A1_msw, "\\[.*\\d]\\","") %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = bigram, input = X1, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>% 
  na.omit(A1_msw)
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Removing `[<digits>]`s is done with `gsub("\\[[0-9]+]", "", A1_msw)`. Deleting all `[...]` is done with `"\\[[^][]*]"`. See [Remove any text inside square brackets in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677243/remove-any-text-inside-square-brackets-in-r/52677485#52677485)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It still doesn't work though and I get the following error message: 
"Error in gsub(., "\\[[0-9]+]", "", A1_msw) : 
  invalid regular expression 'c("[0001]", "\f", ..."

Comment: In your `%>%` based workflow, it should be `gsub("\\[[0-9]+]", "", .)`, I believe.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Wiktor! I now got rid of all the extra letters and numbers!